# Set specific error pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, exception

In my MVC project i set a Default error page in the web.config

```
<customErrors defaultRedirect="~/Error/Index" mode="RemoteOnly">
</customErrors>
```

till now all is fine, in any exception thrown the user get the default error page.

Now i want to add another error page that in specific exception will load instead of the default error page that set in the web.config.

I had an idea: maybe in a new class that inherit "ActionFilterAttribute" and implement "IExceptionFilter", i will in any exception thrown from an action if the type of the exception is my specific case, in this case i need to change the redirect route that set in the web.config as default, but how can i do it? or maybe someone have an another idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change anything in the web.config. The `customErrors` in the catches only the exceptions you didn't catch in yours ActionFilters and Controllers.

Good plan Boss!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

And [read this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619895/how-can-i-properly-handle-404-in-asp-net-mvc/7499406#7499406) about how I do it, etc. It might help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify what views are rendered for a given exception with the [HandleErrorAttribute filter](http://community.codesmithtools.com/CodeSmith_Community/b/tdupont/archive/2011/03/01/error-handling-and-customerrors-and-mvc3-oh-my.aspx)